# In what OS folder should I create a hidden file to denote that my client's license has expired?

Tags: linux, windows, security, unix, filesystems

I understand this is not 100% safe but it is at least something. After my software license expires I would like to write a hidden file **somewhere** that my software can later check to see if the license has expired. That way, even if the client re-installs the software it won't work because the file will be there. What location/folder do you suggest that I do that for Linux, Unix, Windows and Mac? Any other simple ideas will be also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows there is of course the Registry. I have also tracked down such files as you describe in `c:\ProgramData`, `c:\Users\User\Appdata\Local`. Note that there are several programs out there that will do "perfect" uninstalls, by taking a snapshot of the file system and registry before any installations. So yes, not 100% safe.

In Linux you can make dot directories in the user's home dir, or write into a `/var` subdirectory created for your program. Most other locations are going to be read-only unless you've convinced the user to run you as root.

On OS X you have the same sort of directories as Linux, and you have property list files where you can store various property values. Those aren't going to be very hidden from a OS X power user, but then none of this stuff is really possible to hide.